# Why isnt this variable an Attributed String?

Tags: objective-c, nsattributedstring

I have these 3 lines in code which are meant to take text from a .txt file and allocate it to an `NSAttributedString`

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"txt"];
NSString *text = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];

NSAttributedString *attString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text];
```

Using the debugger I know that the `path` is being found correctly, and the text is being added to the variable `text` fine, but its not converting to the `NSAttributedString` - the debugger just says "variable is not NSAttributedString"

What am I missing from the third line to allow the NSString to be converted to an NSSAttributedString? (I dont want any attributes, but Im presuming you can just load the string into an attributed string?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might come from somewhere else I guess, just tried :

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"txt"];
NSString *text = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];

NSAttributedString *attString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text];

NSLog(@"Text : %@\nNSAS : %@", text, attString);
```

Here is the output :

```
2013-06-10 11:17:04.444 TestsSO[5554:c07] Text : hello, world !
NSAS : hello, world !{
}
```

Are you sure that `text` is filled correctly ?

Comment: Yes, in the debugger i can run the command po text and it gives the entire text file.  It just doesnt seem to want to convert to an attributed string! im sure i just missing out a small detail but i cant figure out what it is!

Comment: Any special content in the file ? As I said, the code above works for me.

Comment: no, just basic text with a little bit of markup in it, which I presume is part of the NSUTF8 encoding - just the usual symbols included, nothing out of the ordinary

Comment: Could you try with a simple content like I did (hello, word !, for example) ?

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
NSAttributedString *attString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text attributes:nil];
```

Hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attri_str=[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:text];


  [attri_str addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:15] range:NSMakeRange(0, 15)]; // Begin and Last letter

        [attri_str addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0 green:143/255.0 blue:255/255.0 alpha:0.75] range:NSMakeRange(0,25)];
```

I hope it help for you.