# Variable is not NSAttributedString?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am trying to create an empty `NSMutableAttributedString`:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *aString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] init];
```

The code compiles just fine, but the Xcode debugger tells me that `@<variable is not an NSAttributedString>`. Curious, I tried different ways of creating it, including `initWithString:@""`. I then decided to see if I could make non-mutable attributed strings:

```
NSAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"test"];
```

This worked just fine; the debugger showed me an attributed string with "test" as its contents. I then decided to try the following kludge:

```
NSAttributedString *aString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"test"];
NSMutableAttributedString *mString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:aString];
```

Sadly, while `aString` gets created just fine, the debugger reports that `mString` is not an NSAttributedString, just as before.

What am I missing? I've checked out other questions on this site, including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17020396/why-isnt-this-variable-an-attributed-string), but haven't been able to find an answer. Everything I've read suggests that my initial usage of the class is correct.

Thanks.

Comment: [A related Twitter account.](https://twitter.com/wtfxcode)

Comment: Did you try to `NSLog();` them

Answer (score 0):

Above question made me re-look at my code. It seems that debug message was irrelevant; what the actual problem was (and why nothing was displaying) was because I was using a font name (NSString) instead of a font object (NSFont) when setting the attributes of the string.

Here's a link to the solution:
[Why does [NSTextStorage setAttributedString] crash with NSMutableAttributedString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11153810/why-does-nstextstorage-setattributedstring-crash-with-nsmutableattributedstrin)